# How to update two entities/model elements from one jsp in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, crud

My requirement is to do a CREATE operation by providing the user with a form in a JSP with input fields from two entities (e.g. **UserDetails** and **EmploymentDetails**)

What is the most effective way to update two forms in a single jsp using a single submit?

One approach I know of is to combine the two entities into a single wrapper-class and then send that object as Model. Is that the only solution?

Kindly guide.

Comment: Do you really have two diffenent HTML Forms, or only two entities/modelelements/command-objects in the same HTML Form?

Comment: @Ralph, Actually I've only one form but it consists of two entities/model-elements. Till now I've been wrapping both around another class & then using it. Now just wondering if there's a better way out.

Comment: then please correct your question! -- it is very confusing.

Comment: sure? >"What is the most effective way to update two forms in a single jsp using a single submit?" --- Every body that answer your question spend a lot of time for helping you, so please be so fair and spend too to write good question.

Answer (score 6):

It's a common practice to put any number of objects in a wrapper class and use this one to submit data with a single form. Additionally, you can use JSR-303 validation in any of objects:

```
public class MyForm {

    @Valid
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    @Valid
    private EmploymentDetails employmentDetails;

    ...

}
```

your form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="myForm" method="post">
    <form:input path="userDetails.property1"/>
    <form:input path="userDetails.property2"/>
    <form:input path="employmentDetails.property1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="create"/>
</form:form>
```

and your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create (@Valid MyForm myForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // here you can retrieve form errors of both objects
    }

    UserDetails userDetails = myForm.getUserDetails();
    EmploymentDetails employmentDetails = myForm.getEmploymentDetails();

    ...

}
```

Another approach is to save objects via JSON, but I think is overkill and overcomplicated in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've been doing this approach in my earlier projects in Spring MVC, but just wondering if there's a better solution. I don't know everything & Spring has matured a lot since my last project, hence asked.

Answer (score 0):

Could try mapping each object to different model attribute:

```
public String create(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="UserDetails") UserDetails userDetails,
   @Valid @ModelAttribute(value="EmploymentDetails") EmploymentDetails employmentDetails, 
   BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)  
{
```

In the form, these should be bound to different prefixes, eg:

```
<form:input path="UserDetails.name" />
```

Comment: Are you sure this method will work? I need to try it. At first glance looks like one of the model attribute won't be recognized. Have you implemented it?

Comment: Not tried it myself.
Not sure about binding result either.
I would be interested to know though..